# Signing JNLP file with dynamic arguments

Tags: java-web-start, jnlp

I am signing a JNLP file having APPLICATION.JNLP in jar file under folder JNLP-INF. My APPLICATION.JNLP placed in the jar looks as shown below

```
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="https://www.example.com:7008/abc">
<information>
    <title>XYZ</title>
    <vendor>XYZ</vendor>
    <description>XYZ</description>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" />
    <jar href="abc.jar" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="tempclass.Class1">
    <argument>*</argument>
    <argument>*</argument>
    <argument>*</argument>
    <argument>*</argument>
    <argument>*</argument>
    <argument>*</argument>
    <argument>*</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

My generated JNLP file from jsp is shown below

```
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="https://www.example.com:7008/abc">
<information>
    <title>XYZ</title>
    <vendor>XYZ</vendor>
    <description>XYZ</description>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" />
    <jar href="abc.jar" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="tempclass.Class1">
    <argument>1</argument>
    <argument>2</argument>
    <argument>3</argument>
    <argument>4</argument>
    <argument>5</argument>
    <argument>6</argument>
    <argument>7</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The issue I am facing is on using this APPLICATION.JNLP I am getting "Signed JNLP file do not match with the downloaded jnlp file". On adding exact argument parameters it works. I want to use dynamic launching parameters. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 Update 161 you can define secure arguments within your JNLP. 
Insert the property inside the `resources` element

```
  <property name="jnlp.secure.argument.<argument-name>" value="true"/>
```

You can also use a wildcard, so that all arguments are marked secure

```
  <property name="jnlp.secure.argument.*" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Google finds only 3 hits: this page, your similar answer on another SO question and one JDK bug.
I tried this with a local JNLP file with Java 8u171 but if I change a param, it asks for permission again on start.

Comment: Ignore that, this is about application arguments, while I was actually testing applet params.

Comment: It seems the `jnlp.secure.argument` works only for <argument> elements but not for <param> elements that are used for applets. There '<property name="jnlp.secure.parameter.<name or *>" value="true"/>' must be used.

Answer (score 1):

If I read the doc correctly, the JNLP template in the signed .jar file should be named JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP

JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP is for the no dynamic case.